# how to Change message body text bold in message composer

Tags: objective-c

hi I need to change text to bold in message composer body pls help me , I've tried with attributed text but I couldn't add

```
NSMutableAttributedString *yourAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message];
NSString *boldString = @"hey";
NSRange boldRange = [message rangeOfString:boldString];
[yourAttributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] range:boldRange];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
lbl.attributedText = yourAttributedString;
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposeVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
messageComposeVC.recipients = selectedContacts;
messageComposeVC.body = [lbl.attributedText string];

[self presentViewController:messageComposeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't think that `MFMessageComposeViewController` allows it, since `body` expect a `NSString`, not a `NSAttributedString`. Also, why the use of `lbl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better if you initiate a attribute to hold all your text attributes ( text size, font , colors ,weight ,styles) and add that when you are initializing the text , in your case "yourAttributedString" . Not sure if there is a specific reason to as why you do this so but try the following .

Use LocalizedStandardRangeofString instead or RangeOfString as you are 
displaying this text.Check the "important" section in this documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-rangeofstring?language=objc

```
//make an attributes dictionary here.
NSDictionary *stringAttributes = @{
NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]
    };

NSString *message = @" message hey";
NSMutableAttributedString *yourAttributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:message];

NSString *boldString = @"hey";
NSRange range = [message localizedStandardRangeOfString:boldString];

[yourAttributedString addAttributes:stringAttributes range:range];

self.lbl.attributedText = yourAttributedString;
```